# Iterate props an classes through SASS

Tags: css, loops, for-loop, sass, iteration

I have 2 tags `a.tag`, and I need to set the backgrounds using variables and iteration.

```
&.tag:nth-og-type(N) {
background: '$grad' + N
}
```

I tried this:

**variables.scss**

```
$grad: linear-gradient(to right, #d24a17, #7e490b),
linear-gradient(to right, #68bd25, #60801d), linear-gradient(#88ade4, #2a77b6),
linear-gradient(to right, #b0d925, #be8516), linear-gradient(to right, #251c8e, #0f2454);
```

**style.scss**

```
@import url('./variables.scss');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif !important;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  #topNav & {
    color: black;
  }
  #topNav &:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white
  }
  &.tag {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    &:hover {
      color: lightgrey
    }
    @each $item in $grad {
      &:nth-of-type(#{$item}) {
        background: $item
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And I tried this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 5 {
      a.tag {
        background: '$grad' + #{$i}
      }
    }
```

But it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a value from a **list variable** within a **for directive**, you need to use the [nth function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method), which takes two parameters: `$list` and `$n`.

**Demo:**

```
@for $i from 1 through length($grad) {
  a.tag:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    background: nth($grad, $i);
  }
}
```

Note that you can rely on the [length function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#length-instance_method) to get the length of your list, instead of using a fixed number for the `<end>` parameter of your **for directive**.

Complete code: [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/5b7bbb15db292b99956869ff75d98f82)

Comment: Undefined variable "$grad". Why?

Comment: Don't remove your '$grad' variable